# cant get success message of ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I don't know why I couldnt get the sucess message in JSON. The data is inserted good to database, so it works but the callback message (success ) no. I don't know why.

this file is where to insert data in database.

```
include ("connect_to_mysql.php");
if ( isset($_POST['register'])) {
    $First_Name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['firstname']);
    $Last_Name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['lastname']);
    $Email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
    $Password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
    $Gender = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['gender']);

    $sql3 =mysql_query("SELECT email FROM members WHERE email = '$Email' ");
    $result3= mysql_num_rows($sql3) ;
    $found ='';
    if ($result3 == 1 ) { 
        $found = "email already exist ! ";
    } else {
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO members (firstname, lastname,gender, email, password,bio_body, sign_up_date , account_type)
        VALUES( '".$First_Name."', '".$Last_Name."','".$Gender."','".$Email."','".$Password."','NULL' ,NOW() , 'a' )  ");
        $found = "registered succefully !";
    }
    echo json_encode(array('returned_val' => "$found"));
    //-- i have tried this also echo json_encode(array('returned_val' => $found));
}
```

this is my ajax

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#register').click(function() {
        $('#mydata').html('Saving your data...<img src="images/loading.gif" />');
        $.ajax({
            url: "sendata.php",
            dataType: 'json' ,
            data: {
                firstname: firstname.value,
                lastname: lastname.value,
                email: email.value,
                password: password.value,
                gender: gender.value
            },
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(data){
                $('#mydata').html("<span style='font-size:18px; color: green;'> Your data is saved succefully! </span>").delay(3000).fadeOut('fast');
                alert(data.returned_val);
                alert (1);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

OBS: about mysql or some security stuff (passowrd) I know , I will fix them when I fix this problem.

thanks for your time.

Edit: I have no error message

EDIT. html form

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <table width="100%" class="noborder" >
        <tr>
            <td width="23%" height="47" class="right">First Name:</td>
            <td width="77%" class="left left_nowrap">
                <input type="text" class="left left_nowrap tb10  border1" name ="firstname" id="First_Name" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['firstname'];  ?>" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td height="47" class="right">Last Name:</td>
            <td valign="middle" class="left left_nowrap">
                <input type="text" class="left  left_nowrap tb10 border1" name ="lastname" id="Last_Name"  value="<?php echo  $_SESSION['lastname'];  ?>" /><br/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            ........
            <td valign="middle" class="left"><input id="register" name="register" type="button" class="submit1 tb10 border4" value="Sign - Up" /></td>
```

Comment: Add an error handler, see why it is erroring out.

Comment: there is no error , data is inserted but dont get back success message

Comment: You don't parse the data once you get them in JavaScript, use `JSON.parse` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse or the jQuery `$.parseJSON()` http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/, otherwise you have just a string...

Comment: yes its just string i want get , look $found . its just string

Comment: NOTE: **success()** is deprecated. use `.done()` instead.

Comment: @echo_me `data` is a string so there is no `data.returned_val` you have to parse the string to make it an object like this `data = JSON.parse(data)` then you'll have an object.

Comment: @itachi i have `success: function(){` how it will be with done like that `done: function(){` ?

Comment: @xpy added `data = JSON.parse(data)` and not working, as u see i also alert(1); but didnt alert so the problem maybe in sendata file

Comment: erm.... see the docs? http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: you simply wrote `alert(1)` **(without all those tags, fadeouts, delays)** and it didn't output?

Comment: @itachi well , used done() i got this error `SyntaxError: missing : after property id
 
done(function(){`

Comment: Is there an HTML form? Can we see it?

Comment: I also suspect that `$_POST['register']` is not set... It seems like you don't send it with the data.

Comment: no its set it echo normal i said it register normal in database

Comment: So... You propably post the form data normaly with the form and then you also do the ajax request. That's why you have a succesfull POST and no data returned. Try preventing the form from sending : `<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return (false)">` and then see if you ajax request really work.

Comment: no its not that. i added onsubmit and no message back also .

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `error` callback ([documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)) that will be triggered if jQuery thinks that something has gone wrong sending the data, for example:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "sendata.php",
  dataType: 'json' ,
  data: {
    firstname : firstname.value,
    lastname : lastname.value,
    email : email.value,
    password : password.value,
    gender : gender.value
  },
  type : 'POST',
  success: function(data){
    $('#mydata').html("<span style='font-size:18px; color: green;'> Your data is saved succefully! </span>").delay(3000).fadeOut('fast');
    alert(data.returned_val);
    alert (1);
  },
  error: function(data){
    console.log(data);
  }
});
```

By looking at the data printed in the console, you should be able to tell why jQuery doesn't invoke your success callback.

Comment: He might not see any kind of error if that is not allowed on the php side.

Comment: Since he has no errors in his console, and the `success` callback is never fired, the only explanation seems to be that for some reason the `error` callback gets fired.

Comment: got this `Object { readyState=

4

, responseText=

"<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "...ody>\r\n</body>\r\n</html>\r"

, status=

200

, more...}
`

Comment: Did this only appear after you added the `error` callback like I suggested? Because the `status=200` part should tell jQuery that everything is fine and that the `success` callback should be invoked...

Comment: Try replacing your `success` and `error` callbacks with the following: `success: function(data) { alert('success'); },
error: function(data){ alert('error'); },`. Which alert appears?

Comment: nothing comes , allthe time and this loading.gif turning and data register in database but nothing back

Comment: after your last suggestion here

Comment: Well if it takes a long time, that's probably just the timeout firing. But it's difficult to help you without direct access. Try debugging the error by doing: `error: function(data){ console.log(data); }` and then inspect the error data.

Comment: it doesnt take long time it me i pasted ur last code and i left some of your first code.

Comment: console log didnt show anything just this i showed u up 17mins ago.

Comment: with console log i get this `responseText
 

"<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2//EN">

<html>

<head>

<title></title>

</head>

<body>

</body>

</html>
"`

Comment: should i make doctype and head and body tags in sendata.php file ??

Answer (score 0):

You should check the PHP error log. There has to be something there. Your javascript is not getting back any answer, probably, due to some error on the PHP side. If there is nothing in the PHP error log, then implement the error handler in the ajax request, there has to be something there.

Comment: i have made the exact php code in the file of ajax and it echo normal . no errors

Comment: Well, if you have no js error, and no php error, then maybe you get redirected somehow. Can I see this anywhere? Where I can test it?

Answer (score -1):

Use `console.log(data)` to quickly validate ajax response.

Comment: where ? in which file i use it?

Comment: in your ajax code, after line "success: function(data){"

use Firebug in Firefox browser

Comment: didnt do nothing , i checked with firebug ,and no error there just the file sendata.php 200 ok 8ms

Comment: remove all those tags, delays, fadeout and do a simple alert. plus see the console. there is an error there.

Comment: have already done a simple alert with alert(1) ; as u see in the code above